# Remove outliers (+/- 3 std) and replace with np.nan in Python/pandas

Tags: python, grouping, outliers

I have seen several solutions that come close to solving my problem

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20889300/4638859)
[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199796/detect-and-exclude-outliers-in-pandas-dataframe?rq=1)

but they have not helped me succeed thus far.

I believe that the following solution is what I need, but continue to get an error (and I don't have the reputation points to comment/question on it): [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27638743/pandas-replace-outliers-with-groupby-mean)

(I get the following error, but I don't understand where to `.copy()` or add an "`inplace=True`" when administering the following command `df2=df.groupby('install_site').transform(replace)`:

SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using `.loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value` instead

See the the caveats in the documentation: [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)

SO, I have attempted to come up with my own version, but I keep getting stuck. Here goes.

I have a data frame indexed by time with columns for site (string values for many different sites) and float values.

```
time_index            site       val
```

I would like to go through the 'val' column, grouped by site, and replace any outliers (those +/- 3 standard deviations from the mean) with a NaN (for each group).

When I use the following function, I cannot index the data frame with my vector of True/Falses:

```
def replace_outliers_with_nan(df, stdvs):
    dfnew=pd.DataFrame()
    for i, col in enumerate(df.sites.unique()):
        dftmp = pd.DataFrame(df[df.sites==col])
        idx = [np.abs(dftmp-dftmp.mean())<=(stdvs*dftmp.std())] #boolean vector of T/F's
        dftmp[idx==False]=np.nan  #this is where the problem lies, I believe
        dfnew[col] = dftmp
    return dfnew
```

In addition, I fear the above function will take a very long time on 7 million+ rows, which is why I was hoping to use the groupby function option.

Comment: That error you get is just a warning.  It seems to sometimes come up even when the operation succeeds.  Did you check whether using that method actually works despite the message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I have understood you right, there is no need to iterate over the columns. This solution replaces all values which deviates more than three group standard deviations  with NaN.

```
def replace(group, stds):
    group[np.abs(group - group.mean()) > stds * group.std()] = np.nan
    return group

# df is your DataFrame
df.loc[:, df.columns != group_column] = df.groupby(group_column).transform(lambda g: replace(g, 3))
```

Comment: Thanks so much @RickardSjogren. This works great!  I do get the indexing-view-versus-copy error, but it works in the end. Much appreciated!!

Comment: could you suggest a way to apply this independently to each column of a dataframe (i.e., replace values that are > 3std from the mean for each column)?  I am struggling to get it working and I keep ending up with an empty dataframe.

Comment: I was hoping you could help me with the above, @RickardSjogren

Comment: This solution should perform the transformation column-wise. A dataframe filled with NaN:s might be due to missing values in your original data which messes up the `mean` and `std`-calls. Without seeing your data I'm not able to troubleshoot though.

Comment: How is `group_column` defined?

Comment: It's the identifier of the column with group belongings which you want to use, e.g. "class".