# Transforming outliers in Pandas DataFrame using .apply, .applymap, .groupby

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, outliers

I'm attempting to transform a pandas DataFrame object into a new object that contains a classification of the points based upon some simple thresholds:

- Value transformed to `0` if the point is `NaN`
- Value transformed to `1` if the point is negative or 0
- Value transformed to `2` if it falls outside certain criteria based on the entire column
- Value is `3` otherwise

Here is a very simple self-contained example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[np.nan,1000000,3,4,5,0,-7,9,10],'b':[2,3,-4,5,6,1000000,7,9,np.nan]})

print(df)
```

[image]

The transformation process created so far:

```
#Loop through and find points greater than the mean -- in this simple example, these are the 'outliers'
outliers = pd.DataFrame()
for datapoint in df.columns:
    tempser = pd.DataFrame(df[datapoint][np.abs(df[datapoint]) > (df[datapoint].mean())])
    outliers = pd.merge(outliers, tempser, right_index=True, left_index=True, how='outer')

outliers[outliers.isnull() == False] = 2


#Classify everything else as "3"
df[df > 0] = 3

#Classify negative and zero points as a "1"
df[df <= 0] = 1

#Update with the outliers
df.update(outliers)

#Everything else is a "0"
df.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
```

Resulting in:

[image]

I have tried to use [`.applymap()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) and/or [`.groupby()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) in order to speed up the process with no luck. I found some guidance in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29741062/655733) however, I'm still unsure how `.groupby()` is useful when you're not grouping within a pandas column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a replacement for the outliers part.  It's about 5x faster for your sample data on my computer.

```
>>> pd.DataFrame( np.where( np.abs(df) > df.mean(), 2, df ), columns=df.columns )

    a   b
0 NaN   2
1   2   3
2   3  -4
3   4   5
4   5   6
5   0   2
6  -7   7
7   9   9
8  10 NaN
```

You could also do it with apply, but it will be slower than the `np.where` approach (but approximately the same speed as what you are currently doing), though much simpler.  That's probably a good example of why you should always avoid `apply` if possible, when you care about speed.

```
>>> df[ df.apply( lambda x: abs(x) > x.mean() ) ] = 2
```

You could also do this, which is faster than `apply` but slower than `np.where`:

```
>>> mask = np.abs(df) > df.mean()
>>> df[mask] = 2
```

Of course, these things don't always scale linearly, so test them on your real data and see how that compares.

Comment: For the outlier part, I only want values to be replaced with `2` when they meet the conditional statement only for their column, **not the whole dataframe** -- I think your solutions use the whole dataframe?

Comment: @cmiller8  No, it's per column. Type `df.mean()` and you will see that it gives you a mean for each column. You could also try some different sample data to test it.

Comment: you're right! AND your method is 300x faster a 10k column, 25k row dataframe